# Closing listener Gluon Mobile

Tags: javafx, gluon

I have a gluon mobile app and need a listener for closing the app. I´ve tried with the method: "setOnCloseRequest" of the stage, but nothing happens. If i use "setOnHinding" it just triggers if i close the app in eclipse. I´ve also tried with the Livecylce Service as the Lifecycle Event "PAUSED", but it only triggers when setting the app to background. Any ideas here?

Comment: Mobile or desktop app? With "listener for closing" you mean to listen when the user closes the app? The LifecycleService only listens to `resume` or `pause` events, when the app gets killed, there is nothing that can trace that anymore.

Comment: Hey, its a mobile app. Thats exactly what I meant with listener for closing. Ok thats sad, but thanks for your help.